# Using fillna method on multiple columns of a Pandas DataFrame failed

Tags: python, pandas, na

Why would this operation fail?
For example:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,np.nan, np.nan],
                 'b': [5,np.nan,6, np.nan],
                 'c': [5, 1, 5, 2]})


a[['a', 'b']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

and gave me this warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

But `a` was still Filled with `NA`s as before. However, if I call `.fillna()` on each column separately, there'd be no issue. How can I fill `NA` values on multiple columns in one shot?

Comment: Just a.fillna(0, inplace = True)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These answers are guided by the fact that OP wanted an in place edit of an existing dataframe.  Usually, I overwrite the existing dataframe with a new one.

---

#### Use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` with a `dict`

Pandas `fillna` allows us to pass a dictionary that specifies which columns will be filled in and with what.

So this will work

```
a.fillna({'a': 0, 'b': 0})

     a    b  c
0  1.0  5.0  5
1  2.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  6.0  5
3  0.0  0.0  2
```

With an in place edit made possible with:

```
a.fillna({'a': 0, 'b': 0}, inplace=True)
```

***NOTE***:  I would've just done this `a = a.fillna({'a': 0, 'b': 0})`

We don't save text length but we could get cute using `dict.fromkeys`

```
a.fillna(dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], 0), inplace=True)
```

---

#### `loc`

We can use the same format as the OP but place it in the correct columns using `loc`

```
a.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] = a[['a', 'b']].fillna(0)

a

     a    b  c
0  1.0  5.0  5
1  2.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  6.0  5
3  0.0  0.0  2
```

---

#### `pandas.DataFrame.update`

Explicitly made to make in place edits with the non-null values of another dataframe

```
a.update(a[['a', 'b']].fillna(0))

a

     a    b  c
0  1.0  5.0  5
1  2.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  6.0  5
3  0.0  0.0  2
```

---

#### Iterate column by column

I really don't like this approach because it is unnecessarily verbose

```
for col in ['a', 'b']:
    a[col].fillna(0, inplace=True)

a

     a    b  c
0  1.0  5.0  5
1  2.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  6.0  5
3  0.0  0.0  2
```

---

#### `fillna` with a dataframe

Use the result of `a[['a', 'b']].fillna(0)` as the input for another `fillna`.  In my opinion, this is silly.  Just use the first option.

```
a.fillna(a[['a', 'b']].fillna(0), inplace=True)

a

     a    b  c
0  1.0  5.0  5
1  2.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  6.0  5
3  0.0  0.0  2
```

Comment: You beat me by 25 seconds:)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why is there such a difference between `fillna` on multiple columns and a single column, even with flagging both `inplace=True`?

Comment: Because `a[['a', 'b']]` is a view/slice and will produce the warning when you use `inplace=True`.  `a.loc[: ['a', 'b']]` won't give a warning with `inplace=True`, but it's doing it on a copy which isn't helpful.  My ***Option 4*** shows it with an `inplace=True` because I'm operating on `a` itself but filling with another dataframe in which I've filled already... btw ***Option 4*** is absurd, please don't actually use it.

Comment: Does this mean that the best way would be option 3? Because my gut instinct told me to go with no 4 which you've now discouraged me from doing :)

Comment: @Mactilda I've updated the answer to include a new and **preferred** way.

Comment: Thanks - if I wanted to map changes instead as a['c'].map({4: 5, 2: 4, 1: 3}) and with several columns, could I use update then - or would another command be better?

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @Mactilda also, your example dictionary precludes itself from being used in `pandas.DataFrame.replace` but you could indeed use `update`.  But as I said, far better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As @piRSquared pointed out, the first solution should be

```
a.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] = a[['a', 'b']].fillna(0)
```

to fillna in selected columns

or

```
a.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

to fillna in all the columns

Comment: `a.loc[:, ['a', 'b']].fillna(0, inplace=True)` fills the copy.  The second works, but will fill `'c'` if it had nulls

Comment: Oh ok, a bad day i guess:(

Comment: You obviously see how many answers MaxU, jezrael, and I put up... trust me, we've corrected each other many many times.  Get used to it.  I'm happy to have another person actively answering pandas questions.  I'm just looking out for you :-)